# regex_substr to extract unit of measure within a string

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I am new to regexp and trying to extract the unit of measure within a block of string.  Examples of strings are:

- `PRODUCT NAME 3.5G`
- `3.5g PRODUCT NAME`
- `PRODUCT NAME 3.5 GRAMS`
- `PRODUCT NAME 3500MG`

How would I be able to use the regex_substr function in redshift to extract the 3.5G out of the above strings.  Currently using case style

```
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), '3.5G') = '3.5G' then '3.5G'

when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' .5G') = ' .5G' then '.5G'

when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 1/8TH') = ' 1/8TH' then '3.5G'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 1/4') = ' 1/4' then '7G'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 1G') = ' 1G' then '1G'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 2G') = ' 2G' then '1G'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 1.75G') = ' 1.75G' then '1.75G'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 7G') = ' 7G' then '7G'

when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 1/2 ') = ' 1/2 ' and producttype = 'FLOWER' then '14G'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 14G') = ' 14G' then '14G'

when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 3.5 GRAM') = ' 3.5 GRAM' then '3.5G'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' EIGHTH') = ' EIGHTH' then '3.5G'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 1 GRAM') = ' 1 GRAM' then '1G'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 1.75 GRAM') = ' 1.75 GRAM' then '1.75G'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 7 GRAM') = ' 7 GRAM' then '7G'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), '14 GRAM') = '14 GRAM' then '14G'

when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 5 MILLIGRAM') = ' 5 MILLIGRAM' then '5MG'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 5MG') = ' 5MG' then '5MG'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 10MG') = ' 10MG' then '10MG'
when regexp_substr(trim(upper(productname)), ' 25MG') = ' 25MG' then '25MG'
```

Comment: What do you extract from `'PRODUCT NAME 14 GRAM'`?

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some ancient roots, they are very different database products

Comment: Using redshift right now.  14GRAM was a bad example but there are other uom types like ML, MG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is `regexp_replace()`:

```
with t as (
      select 'PRODUCT NAME 3.5G' as str union all
      select '3.5g PRODUCT NAME' as str union all
      select 'PRODUCT NAME 3.5 GRAMS' as str union all
      select 'PRODUCT NAME 14 GRAM'
      )
select t.*, regexp_replace(' ' || str, '^.*[^.0-9]([\.0-9]+) ?[gG].*$', '\1')
from t;
```

You can also use:

```
regexp_replace(str, '(^.*[^.0-9]|^)([\.0-9]+) ?[gG].*$', '\2')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, using rexexp_replace above results in:  https://imgur.com/a/pYCoPgI    Separately, if there are other units of measure like (ml, mg, etc), how would i add more variations to the regex pattern?

Comment: @user1615573 . . . This answers the question you have here.  If you have a new question, you should ask it as a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.